# Некорректная работа единиц vw при отсутствии настроек вьюпорта

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, viewport

**Браузер Google Chrome.**

- Разбирался с формулой отзывчивого шрифта:

  ```
   font-size: calc(24px + (40px - 24px) * ((100vw - 320px) / (1280 - 320)));
  ```

где **24px** - размер шрифта для макета минимальной ширины,
**40px** - размер шрифта для макета максимальной ширины,
**320px** - та самая минимальная ширина макета,
**1280px** - максимальная ширина макета.
Столкнулся с проблемой, что в Google Chrome, когда ширина области просмотра становится менее 980px, размер шрифта останавливается на одном значении и перестаёт уменьшаться при дальнейшем сужении вьюпорта. Затем проверил страницу в **Firefox** - всё работало корректно. Однако хотелось понять, что же всё-таки с GH?

Как выяснилось позже, загвоздка была в HTML документе, отсутствовала настройка вьюпорта:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Кто-нибудь может раскрыть подобное поведение Google Chrome и Firefox?